# Objective C setup auto row height in code

Tags: ios, constraints, tableview

I'm working with an old Objective-C project which has not any storyboard. I need a `UITableView` to display the result with `UITableViewCell` that contains 3 labels. The task is to align 3 labels vertically in the `UITableviewCell`

Here is my Label initiation:

```
serviceTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 200, LONG_MAX)];
[serviceTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont SingPostRegularFontOfSize:16.0f fontKey:kSingPostFontOpenSans]];
[serviceTitleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[serviceTitleLabel setTextColor:RGB(51, 51, 51)];
[serviceTitleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[serviceTitleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[contentView addSubview:serviceTitleLabel];

statusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 200, 30)];
[statusLabel setFont:[UIFont SingPostBoldFontOfSize:12.0f fontKey:kSingPostFontOpenSans]];
[statusLabel setTextColor:RGB(125, 136, 149)];
[statusLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[contentView addSubview:statusLabel];

costLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(216, 20, 85, 30)];
costLabel.right = contentView.right - 15;
[costLabel setFont:[UIFont SingPostBoldFontOfSize:16.0f fontKey:kSingPostFontOpenSans]];
[costLabel setTextColor:RGB(51, 51, 51)];
[costLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
[costLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[contentView addSubview:costLabel];
```

How can we adjust in `UITableViewController` so that the size will resize according to the label size? Need to set up in both cell and tableview? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

This is the screen now. Look not right

[image]

Comment: it is not clear to me if you only have one tableView with one cell or more than one cell

Comment: Hi it's a dynamic tableview with data is from an array of items (3 label is the item attribute)

Comment: what I need to understand is if each cell should have its custom height or the calculated height is valid for every cell

Comment: Hi calculate height is valid for every cell! just need to align the 3 label vertically and resize the row so that row height contain 3 label text not overlap

Comment: just to make your question clearer, can you post a screen of out it looks currently?

Comment: For dynamic table and cell height which depends on label height, check [this](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/09/uitable-view-cell-dynamic-height-ios7.html).

Comment: Hi I'm following the article but seem not work. maybe because i'm using customs cell not the prototype cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to manage the cell height as per the content. For that you have to set the constraint of your labels from all the sides, ie Click on the PIN and then uncheck the `Constraint from margin` check box and for both of your labels add constraints from Top, bottom, Left and Right side.As it is required if you want to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Now in the `ViewController` in `viewDidLoad` method add this two line

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: Thanks my prob is i don't have storyboard. all need to do in code

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on your iOS deployment target. If it's higher or equal than iOS 8 than:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

This solution works if constraints in cell set properly.

If it's lower than you need to calculate it by yourself, implement UITableViewDelegate

```
- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help where do I put the line self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;? anyway to set the constrain for the cell. only have 3 label in cell

Comment: Set it self.tableView.rowHeight in your tableview controller (for example viewDidLoad). About constraints: you should set constraints for all labels, every table should have constraints for all sides (top, right, bottom, left)

Comment: so need to set contain for all 3 label in code? 4 for 1 label. 12 contains for 3 label? I'm trying the stack view approach. Hope can be simple